# $scope is not updated in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have integrated pagination and sorting in my AngularJS project. I want to show the data according to page per item using user's choice. When I integrate this thing I got problem of updating the scope variable. Here is my code:

```
<div dir-paginate="partners in partnersData|orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort |filter:{name: partners.name, website: partners.website, location: partners.location}|itemsPerPage: limitData as filteredArray" current-page="currentPage">
          <div class="rowDiv">
            <div class="cellDiv"><span   ng-click="makeFavourite(partners)" class="star_rating" ng-class="{'select':partners.select}"></span> <span ng-click="showImage($index)"></span></div>
            <div class="cellDiv" ng-click="showName($index)">{{partners.name}}</div>
            <div class="cellDiv" ng-click="openWebsite(partners.website)">{{partners.website}}</div>
            <div class="cellDiv">{{partners.location}}</div>
            <div class="cellDiv">{{partners.service}}</div>
            <div class="cellDiv">{{partners.connection}}</div>
            <div class="cellDiv">{{partners.action}}</div>
            <div class="cellDiv lastCell"><span class="icon_pluse" ng-click="openPlus($index)"></span><span class="icon_info" ng-click="openInfo($index)"></span></div>
```

I have include the file for pagination and for item per page:

```
<dir-pagination-controls boundary-links="true" on-page-change="pageChangeHandler(newPageNumber)" template-url="templates/dashboard/dirPagination.tpl.html"></dir-pagination-controls>
```

This is the dirPagination.tpl.html file:

```
<select class="filterSelect"  ng-options="limits.value as limits.value for limits in availableLimits" ng-model="limits"  ng-change="selectLimit()">
                        <!--<option style="display:none" value="">Select</option>-->
                    </select>
```

Controller code:

```
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.limitData = 1;               
    $scope.selectLimit = function () 
    {
         //console.log($scope.limits);
         var limits = $scope.limits
         $scope.limitData = limits;
    };
```

Comment: use an object to store currentPage and limitData

Answer (score 0):

Please, refer this code. It's working fine.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Wtkv71LIqUR4OhzhgpqL?p=preview

```
function MyController($scope) {

  $scope.currentPage = 1;
  $scope.pageSize = 10;
  $scope.meals = [];

  var dishes = [
    'noodles',
    'sausage',
    'beans on toast',
    'cheeseburger',
    'battered mars bar',
    'crisp butty',
    'yorkshire pudding',
    'wiener schnitzel',
    'sauerkraut mit ei',
    'salad',
    'onion soup',
    'bak choi',
    'avacado maki'
  ];
  var sides = [
    'with chips',
    'a la king',
    'drizzled with cheese sauce',
    'with a side salad',
    'on toast',
    'with ketchup',
    'on a bed of cabbage',
    'wrapped in streaky bacon',
    'on a stick with cheese',
    'in pitta bread'
  ];
  for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    var dish = dishes[Math.floor(Math.random() * dishes.length)];
    var side = sides[Math.floor(Math.random() * sides.length)];
    $scope.meals.push('meal ' + i + ': ' + dish + ' ' + side);
  }

  $scope.pageChangeHandler = function(num) {
      console.log('meals page changed to ' + num);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the problem of scope inheritance in Angular or in Javascript. Read more on this [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

To fix your problem, first define an object like this:

```
$scope.modelData = {};
$scope.modelData.currentPage = 1;
$scope.modelData.limitData = 1;

$scope.selectLimit = function() {
     $scope.modelData.limitData = $scope.limits;
};
```

Now, update your views to use the new object `$scope.modelData` (I'm writing it at one place, you can fix this at other places if any):

```
<div dir-paginate="partners in partnersData|orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort |filter:{name: partners.name, website: partners.website, location: partners.location}|itemsPerPage: modelData.limitData as filteredArray"
     current-page="modelData.currentPage"></div>
```

Defining an object `$scope.modelData` and using it all the places will eliminate the problem of nested scope which is being created by the `repeat` expression.

Answer (score -1):

Are you missing an ";" in the end of `var limits = $scope.limits` ? Sometimes JS drives you crazy with these types of errors.